# Why TypeScript cannot resolve assignment in object destructuring?

Tags: typescript

Let's have a following code:

```js
interface Foo {
    a?: number
    b?: number
}

function foo(options?: Foo) {
    const {
        a, // <-- error here
        b = a
    } = (options ?? {})

    return [a, b]
}
```

Why this code fails with:

> 'a' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.

Doesn't `a` have type `number | undefined`?

However, if I rewrite the `foo` function to:

```js
function foo(options?: Foo) {
    const f = options ?? {}
    
    const {
        a,
        b = a
    } = f

    return [a, b]
}
```

No error is emitted.

Why? Is it a bug?

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyRycA-AFzIgCuAtgEbQHHL0VV2NQEC+BBMaiARhg6EMhiYAFOgAOo8QGd2GdAEoczYgmVgthFsTgAabUdbIAvCXPIe15LIViQS5KVI4e6-oaJQEGDUUBIA2qasALq8BEA)

Comment: This may be one of the **very** few questions where "Is it a bug?" is a reasonable thing to ask. :-)

Comment: Here's [another way to write it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyRycA-AFzIgCuAtgEbQHHL0VV2NQEC+BBMaiARhg6EMhiYAFOgAOo8QGdKGLAF4cPAJQ5kAen3IAPOs0ARLGAAWKACYR41ADZhktqBGbEEyt3kIWYjgAGm8g1mRNOHDkHijkeUUQJQBufkCiTzBqKAkAbVDWAF1eAiA) to avoid the problem, but without the `f` identifier.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, I am actually using this way right now. (But I forget why. And I was unable to find an answer here or on github.)

Comment: Wouldn't `const {a, b = a }: Foo = (options ?? {})` work?

Comment: @0stone0 Yes, it would. (But this question is not about how to make to work.)

Comment: I think it's going to end up being a limitation of TS; the inference algorithm will sometimes hit circularities that a clever human could avoid, and there's no simple way to prevent such things in general. See [ms/TS#45213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45213) for example.  Does that fully address the question?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @TN. - I think it would be worth opening an issue for this. If it's a limitation (known or otherwise), that would be good documentation for it, even if the issue ends up being marked as a duplicate. If it *is* a fixable bug, it would be good to get it fixed.

Comment: @jcalz If it is a limitation of TS, I am looking for a issue number. (That I can use as a reference in a source code.) Is the issue you provided "the closest" for this case?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45213 is the closest I've found so far; I can't be sure there isn't something more directly relevant that's eluded my search

Comment: @jcalz - What's circular about the reference in the code above, though? `a` being destructured from an object where `b`'s default value comes from `a`, but only when the type is inferred from the `{}` or something?

Comment: Actually https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49989 might be the closest one.  Why it encounters a circularity is probably that in decides that the type of `b` depends on the type of `a` which it doesn't know yet because it first needs to know the type of the whole object which is composed of `a` and `b`.  It's not the kind of problem a human being would hit when analyzing it, so I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @jcalz - That looks like it, yeah.

Comment: @jcalz Write it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a bug in TypeScript, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#49989](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49989).  A pull request at [microsoft/TypeScript#56753](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/56753) fixes it, so as of TS5.4 this particular problem should no longer be an issue:

[Playground link, TS version 5.4.0-dev.20240111](https://tsplay.dev/WJBgVW)

---

In general, however, TypeScript's type inference algorithm is limited in its ability to avoid circularities.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#45213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45213) for a similar situation that runs into this.  If, when analyzing `const { a, b = a } = options ?? {}`, the compiler decides to, for whatever reason, defer the analysis of `options ?? {}` until after it knows the [context](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) in which it is assigned, then `const { a, b = a }` will be seen as circular since the type of `a` depends on the type of `{a, b}` which depends on the type of `b` which depends on the type of `a`.  Of course a human being would never get caught in such a situation, but the type checker doesn't have the luxury of seeing "the big picture".

While the particular problem you found is indeed considered a bug in TypeScript and had a straightforward fix, there are many similar scenarios classified as a design limitation of the language, because fixing it would require a massive refactoring.  As mentioned in [this comment on microsoft/TypeScript#45213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45213#issuecomment-1018043918):

> It's instructive to look at the call stack at the point that we log the circularity error and see how every caller in that path (of which the incoming call stack is could be practically any function in the checker) would have to be basically completely rewritten to handle the answer of "ask me again later".
>
> We also need to be able to *detect* circularities instead of looping forever. [...] then any sort of work-deferring mechanism needs to be able to detect when it's looping forever so that it doesn't attempt to infer an infinite sequence [...].
>
> The relevant codepaths in the checker here are not especially complicated (relatively speaking) and I'd encourage you to try a PR to understand the problem more deeply. Not to be glib, but if this were low-hanging fruit, we would have done it already . Again, it's not *impossible*, but it's not at all a straightforward fix - we'd have to rewrite very large portions of the entire checker.

Comment: Seems confirmed by author: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/56753#issuecomment-1855626762